# Split on list of strings that may or may not be present

Tags: python

How can I split using a list of strings that may or may not be present in a variable?

```
list_of_passwords = ['Password is', 'Pwd:', 'password:']
my_string = 'This is my string that contains Pwd: 89237'
collected_password = my_string.split(list_of_passwords)[1]

print collected_password
```

But that doesn't work...

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Is the password always the same length? Just take the last five characters in the string.

Comment: No..the password could be any of those strings in the list_of_passwords

Comment: The expected output for collected_password would be:  89237

Why down-vote me?

Comment: Right split once on a space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So split only works with one string at a time (docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split)).  So for your case, where you have a list off possible split strings, we have to loop over each one and try the split:

```
list_of_passwords = ['Password is', 'Pwd:', 'password:']
my_string = 'This is my string that contains Pwd: 89237'
collected_password = None
for x in list_of_passwords:
    pieces = my_string.split(x, 1) # split the string at most 1 time(s)
    if len(pieces) == 2: # we know we had a split if there are two pieces
        collected_password = pieces[-1] # grab the last part of the split

print collected_password.strip()
```

---

You can also do this with regular expressions using re (docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split)):

```
import re

list_of_passwords = ['Password is', 'Pwd:', 'password:']
my_string = 'This is my string that contains Pwd: 89237'
# format the list of passwords separated by the OR
splitter = re.compile('(%s)' % ('|'.join(list_of_passwords)))

pieces = splitter.split(my_string)
collected_password = pieces[-1].strip() # grab the last part of the split
```

Comment: Thank you.  That works.  I'm not sure why I get downvoted for my questions.  I guess I phrase them poorly.  But thank you for understanding and helping.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split):

```
list_of_passwords = ['Password is', 'Pwd:', 'password:']
my_string = 'This is my string that contains Pwd: 89237'

import re

collected_password = re.split(' |'.join(list_of_passwords), my_string)

print(collected_password)
```

output:

```
['This is my string that contains ', '89237']
```